# How to get the selected index document from the firestore?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the selected item index from a list and the data have stored in firestore, What I tried is,

```
   db.collection("Musicians").orderBy("DocumentID", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).limit(30).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){

                List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshotslist= Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getDocuments();
               (DocumentSnapshot document : snapshotslist) {

              //--- This way is not working----------------------------------//
               int index = snapshotslist.indexOf("Flkt8Fb0gWvO9xaUYR0V");//This method always return -1


              //----This way is working--------------------------------//
               int index = snapshotslist.indexOf(document);// This method is working and it gives all index of the list
```

But I only need to get the Index of the document which I entered. For example,

---

- Flkt8Fb0gWvO9xaUYR0V
- BpJQAYm7Y49XA2IZMGhE
- LTy4KuRpXTc5e7FK2I9o
- bxzM9drC9DWDieWEbFLl

---

I want to get the index of "LTy4KuRpXTc5e7FK2I9o" which output is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to find the index of the document in a list, based on its ID.

In that case, you can do:

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshotslist= Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getDocuments();
int index = 0;
for (DocumentSnapshot document : snapshotslist) {
  if (document.getId().equals("Flkt8Fb0gWvO9xaUYR0V")) {
    break;
  }
  index++;
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right I need to get the index of the document in the list based on its ID and I want to set the index to a textview.